# How to properly post JSON data using Ajax to Flask

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

When I log 'export_json' to the console prior to send the data via ajax the data is exactly the way I want it to be. It contains all the features I want. However, when I print the data to flask or write it to a JSON file the features are missing.*The code I have shown here ends up writing nothing to the json file I've created but i've gotten it to write everything but the features before (e.g. what I said I had displayed in powershell down below)*. Does anyone know why the JSON object POSTed doesn't contain features? Please let me know if i'm not being descriptive enough!

Javsacript

```
    console.log(export_json)

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        data: export_json,
        success: function(data){console.log(data)}
    });
```

Python

```
@app.route('/interactive', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def interactive():
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            with open(output_json, 'w') as outfile:
                json.dump(request.get_json(force=True), outfile)

        resp = Response('whathaver')
        return resp
    except Exception, e:
        return (str(e))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here's what's displayed in Powershell:

```
{"displayFieldName":"","fieldAliases":{"FID":"FID","Name_1":"Name_1","LL_X_DD":"LL_X_DD","LL_Y_DD":"LL_Y_DD","Shape_Area
":"Shape_Area","PCT_LAND":"PCT_LAND"},"geometryType":"esriGeometryPolygon","spatialReference":{"wkid":4326,"latestWkid":
4326},"fields":[{"name":"FID","type":"esriFieldTypeOID","alias":"FID"},{"name":"Name_1","type":"esriFieldTypeString","al
ias":"Name_1","length":254},{"name":"LL_X_DD","type":"esriFieldTypeDouble","alias":"LL_X_DD"},{"name":"LL_Y_DD","type":"
esriFieldTypeDouble","alias":"LL_Y_DD"},{"name":"Shape_Area","type":"esriFieldTypeDouble","alias":"Shape_Area"},{"name":
"PCT_LAND","type":"esriFieldTypeInteger","alias":"PCT_LAND"}],"features":[]}
```

There should be features in "features" at the end there. Those features are present when I log 'export_json' to the console though but not present here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

'export_json' how it appears in the console:

```
[object Object]
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      displayFieldName: "",
      features: [ ],
      fieldAliases: { },
      fields: [ ],
      geometryType: "esriGeometryPolygon",
      spatialReference: { }
   }

[object Object]
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      displayFieldName: "",
      features: [
         0: { },
         1: { },
         2: { },
         3: { },
         4: { },
         5: { },
         6: { },
         7: { },
         8: { },
         9: { },
         10: { },
         11: { },
         12: { },
         13: { },
         14: { },
         15: { },
         16: { },
         17: { },
         18: { },
         19: { },
         20: { },
         length: 21
      ],
      fieldAliases: { },
      fields: [ ],
      geometryType: "esriGeometryPolygon",
      spatialReference: {
         [functions]: ,
         __proto__: { },
         latestWkid: 4326,
         wkid: 4326
      }
   }

[object Object]
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      displayFieldName: "",
      features: [
         0: {
            [functions]: ,
            __proto__: {
               [functions]: ,
               __proto__: null
            },
            attributes: {
               [functions]: ,
               __proto__: { },
               FID: 0,
               LL_X_DD: 6,
               LL_Y_DD: 0,
               Name_1: "N0000E00600",
               PCT_LAND: 2,
               Shape_Area: 0.25
            },
            geometry: {
               [functions]: ,
               __proto__: {
                  [functions]: ,
                  __proto__: null
               },
               rings: [
                  0: [
                     0: [
                        0: 6.500000000000057,
                        1: 5.684341886080802e-14,
                        length: 2
                     ],
                     1: [ ],
                     2: [ ],
                     3: [ ],
                     4: [ ],
                     length: 5
                  ],
                  length: 1
               ]
            }
         },
         1: { },
         2: { },
         3: { },
         4: { },
         5: { },
         6: { },
         7: { },
         8: { },
         9: { },
         10: { },
         11: { },
         12: { },
         13: { },
         14: { },
         15: { },
         16: { },
         17: { },
         18: { },
         19: { },
         20: { },
         length: 21
      ],
      fieldAliases: { },
      fields: [ ],
      geometryType: "esriGeometryPolygon",
      spatialReference: { }
   }
```

Comment: Please, provide `export_data` that shows your behaviour.

Comment: I've edited the post. I "copied all" from internet explorer. Is that sufficient? It seems like Internet Explorer only provides a single example down the nested content (if i'm interpreting it correctly).

Comment: Thanks for the guidance guys! I really appreciate it!

Comment: The problem is I stringify the data but it omits the features that should be in the "features" array. Do you have any thoughts on why that is?